# import library without installing

Tags: module, sys.path

I am trying to run a program using a module without having to install it. I tried the `sys.path` instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it), but I keep getting this error:

```
$ python imp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imp.py", line 5, in <module>
    import astropy
  File "./moduly/astropy/__init__.py", line 275, in <module>
    _initialize_astropy()
  File "./moduly/astropy/__init__.py", line 241, in _initialize_astropy
    from .utils import _compiler
ImportError: cannot import name _compiler
```

Please do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This help me

sudo apt-get install python-dev