# Loading python modules in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

How do I load a python module, that is not built in. I'm trying to create a plugin system for a small project im working on. How do I load those "plugins" into python? And, instaed of calling "import module", use a string to reference the module.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it

Answer (score 1):

### Have a look at [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#module-importlib)

#### Option 1: Import an arbitrary file in an arbiatrary path

Assume there's a module at `/path/to/my/custom/module.py` containing the following contents:

```
# /path/to/my/custom/module.py

test_var = 'hello'

def test_func():
    print(test_var)
```

We can import this module using the following code:

```
import importlib.machinery
myfile = '/path/to/my/custom/module.py'
sfl = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('mymod', myfile)
mymod = sfl.load_module()
```

The module is imported and assigned to the variable `mymod`. We can then access the module's contents as:

```
mymod.test_var
# prints 'hello' to the console

mymod.test_func()
# also prints 'hello' to the console
```

#### Option 2: Import a module from a package

Use `importlib.import_module`

For example, if you want to import settings from a settings.py file in your application root folder, you could use

```
_settings = importlib.import_module('settings')
```

The popular task queue package `Celery` uses this a lot, rather than giving you code examples here, please check out their [git repository](https://github.com/celery/celery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=import_module)