# Using python-Levenshtein without install

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I have downloaded python-levenshtein from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/) and I need to use it on a cluster where I do not have sudo abilities. Is there some way to just unzip the contents and use them locally so I can use something like below in a python script?

```
from Levenshtein import distance
```

I suppose this is even a general question as well, in that I would like to know if there is a good way to use python libraries when I do not have the ability to put them in the python2.7 or python3.0 directories.

Thanks.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it

Comment: The link above should be able to answer the question. Personally I like to either make use of the PYTHONPATH environment variable or keep the code in the same working directory as the script being executed.

Comment: What happens if you try to install it in a virtualenv? Do you get errors?

Comment: Three options, two of which Nathan has already covered: 1) Keep code in the same directory, 2) Add the location of your library to PYTHONPATH, and 3) put a `sys.path.append("path/to/lib")` in front of your lib imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-Levenshtein` is not a pure-python implementation, but a library written in C with thin Python bindings. Thus you **must** install it first. To use it without `sudo` rights, you'd might have to create a virtual environment.