# Using packages by providing sys path

Tags: python

I came across this link:

[(Python) Use a library locally instead of installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it)

And followed the steps to provide path to IBPy package which I downloaded and extracted on my desktop.

My code looks like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\IbPy-0.7.6-9.51\build\lib\ib')
import IbPy
```

But the error on third line is: No module named IbPY. I tried different variants on the path for IbPy as: C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\IbPy-0.7.6-9.51

Any suggestions ? My problem is I can't install packages even locally. Only thing I am allowed to do is bring packages through USB.

Edit:

(1) Yes there is **init**.py file

(2) I am now using

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\IbPy-0.7.6-9.51\build\lib\ib')
```

The error is still there.

I am using Pycharm as my editor and I downloaded the IBPy from:

https://github.com/blampe/IbPy

Comment: Does the `ib` folder have `__init__.py`? You may want to create an empty one in order to use functions from there.

Comment: You have a `\x08` in there so you string is appended as `C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\IbPy-0.7.6-9.5uild\lib\ib`

Comment: What's in `r'C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\IbPy-0.7.6-9.51\build\lib\ib'`? From peeking at github, it looks like you should `sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\IbPy-0.7.6-9.51\build\lib')` and `import ib` (not `ibPy`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is the shallowest directory with an `__init__.py` and that directory name is the package name. `sys.path` needs to include the directory before the package directory because python will append the package name to the names in `sys.path` until it finds a match. Since the directory `ib` holds the package `__init__.py` you need to

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\IbPy-0.7.6-9.51\build\lib')
import ib
```

Answer (score 3):

Use raw strings for Windows paths. The `\b` is being interpreted as a backspace character.

```
r'C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\IbPy-0.7.6-9.51\build\lib\ib'
```

should work. Raw strings prevent the interpretation of backslash escapes for all but the string's quote character.