# Python: Using packages by providing sys path

Tags: python

This is a continuation of the question I had asked in another thread:

[Using packages by providing sys path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366057/using-packages-by-providing-sys-path/34366384#34366384)

The sys.path.append idea worked great. I understand that path has to be provided to location of **init**.py. But now I am trying to call a python package written in C which doesn't have **init**.py:

https://github.com/Komnomnomnom/swigibpy/

(1) How do I call the package when it doesn't have **init**.py

(2) When the package is written in C ?

Edit: I am in a situation where I can't install libraries on the machine I will be working on and only access I have is through USB.

I downloaded and extracted swigibipy on my desktop.
I tried the following:

```
import sys    
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Duck\Desktop\swigibpy-master')
import swigibpy
```

But the error is:

```
No module named swigibpy
```

Comment: If it doesn't have an `__init__.py` it's not a package. The difference between a directory and a package is that a package has a file called `__init__.py` in it. However, in your case swigibpy is a module, not a package, and you can just do 'import swigibpy', as the README at your link shows.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to install these libraries. At least use a virtualenv.