# How to use blist module without installing it?

Tags: python

Without installing `blist`, I am trying to use blist_1.3.6 module by setting the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. However I am still getting the error below. Is there any way to use this `_blist` without installing it? I can see `_blist.c` is C language file.

```
File "/path/blist-1.3.6/blist/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from blist._blist import *
ImportError: No module named _blist
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it

Answer (score 2):

`_blist` is the module implemented by the object that results from compiling `_blist.c` and creating a shared library from it. You can't simply import `_blist.c` directly.