# Python3 use installed modules on another computer

Tags: python-3.x, aes, pycrypto

I have downloaded the pycrypto module for python 3, so I Can use AES in my python code. (EG if I have a code called encodeUsingAES.py)

However, this wouldn't work if I just copied encodeUsingAES.py to a different computer and ran it right? Because it doesn't have the pycrypto module installed so it will pop up heaps of errors.

I tried just copying the Crypto folders inside pycrypto into the same directory as my .py file but it didn't work.

Is there anyway for my to have all the files I need in the same directory so when I compress and send the folder the recipient can just run the .py file without having to install extra modules?

Thanks!

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

EDIT:
Tried this didn't work

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/pycrypto")
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

$ python3 testCrypto.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "testCrypto.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

or

```
import sys
sys.path.append("pycrypto/lib")
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

$ python3 testCrypto.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "testCrypto.py", line 5, in <module>
      from Crypto import Random
     File "pycrypto/lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
      from Crypto.Random import OSRNG
    File "pycrypto/lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
      from Crypto.Random.OSRNG.posix import new
    File "pycrypto/lib/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/posix.py", line 66
      except IOError, e:
```

Comment: If you use the path `/pycrypto`, it means that pycrypto is a folder in the root of your system. If you remove the `/` the directory should be relative to your working directory.

Comment: @PinkFluffyUnicorn same thing,   File "testCrypto.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it should help you

Answer (score 0):

If you copy the complete folder, you should add it to your path to be able to import it.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/crypto/directory")

from Crypto import Random
```

If the pycrypto folder is directly placed in your project folder, following statement should work.

`sys.path.append('./pycrypto')`

Comment: but lots of files inside Crypto.Random has "from Crypto import Someotherthing", they don't have sys.path.append so they can't find the correct files?

Comment: I think sys.path is linked to your Python session, so once you modify your path, it should be visible in all python files. Or do you experience issues with this ?