# Error when trying to check for pressed key

Tags: python

I am trying to use a simple event listener.

This is what I have so far:

```
import keyboard 
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        print('You pressed P')
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'is_pressed'

When I check the [documentation](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.is_pressed), I see that `is_pressed` exists.

Is there something wrong with the library or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It works for me, just like you typed.

Comment: Have you made sure to properly install the keyboard module and such cause it seemed to work for me.

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the right module? Try `print(keyboard.__file__)` to see what you're importing.

Comment: @Rawing I get `AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute '__file__'`. I am using Python version 3.6.1. Could that be an issue? I have downloaded keyboard from git. It's on my project directory. And I use Windows.

Comment: @RezaSaadati I believe that's the problem -- try doing `sudo pip install keyboard` in command line as mentioned in their docs. Cloning the repository won't hook it into python's package manager. If you want it to work with your local repository, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it)

Comment: Instead of downloading it from git, why not install it with pip? Run `pip install keyboard` in an admin terminal.

Comment: @aug thank you very much! That was definitely the point and it works great now!

Comment: @Rawing thank you for this info! I used `py -m pip install keyboard` and it works like a charm!

Comment: Mine returns `/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pynput/keyboard/__init__.pyc`? When i print my keyboard, but the is_pressed command doesnt work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll add it as a formal answer anyways. You mentioned that you `git clone` the repository. I guess this is confusing since the README says you can either do `pip install` or `git clone` to install the package.

When you do [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), it tells Python to go through it's package manager to find the module and these need to be installed on your end. [`pip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) is the package management system that Python uses

If you want to install a package that you have as a local folder (i.e. if you wanted to test a local module) you can do so see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it)

Answer (score 1):

please try to rename your document. don't put name as "keyboard.py"

Comment: it's funny, but it work for me xD