# using netcdf without installation

Tags: python, netcdf

I need to use netcdf but do not have install permission for python modules. I have downloaded netcdf-0.1.2.tar.gz from here: https://pypi.python.org/simple/netcdf/ and unzipped the tar ball. I have been following this stack overflow post in an attempt to use the module but have had no luck so far:
[(Python) Use a library locally instead of installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it)
here is what I have tried:

Installing virtualenv:
I do not have permission to do this

python setup.py install -- user:
again, I don't have permission

running my script with netcdf as my current working directory:
I tried this as well, here are the issues I have run into:
first I went into netcdf-0.1.2 and made a new file called asdf.py
which contains the following:

```
import netcdf
print("testing")
```

running python asdf.py gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asdf.py", line 1, in <module>
    import netcdf
  File "/.../Downloads/netcdf-0.1.2/netcdf/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from netcdf import *
  File "/.../Downloads/netcdf-0.1.2/netcdf/netcdf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from netCDF4 import Dataset, numpy
ImportError: No module named netCDF4
```

I'm not sure how to fix this error, any help would be greatly appreciated

in case this is somehow relevant, the version of Linux I am using is 3.2.0-23-generic

also I have numpy installed already

Comment: You can install Anaconda/Miniconda into your home dir. This would give all the needed rights.

Comment: @MikeMüller the central issue here is that I can't install anything, if I could I would just install netcdf

Comment: You don't need admin rights only rights to write in your home dir.

Comment: @fred, sorry, I missed that. Now you should search for a module called `netCDF4`. I suspect it's either yet another module that you need to download separately and unpack in such a way that it's visible to `netcdf`, or it's hidden somewhere inside the `netcdf` folder, so that it should be moved in order to be visible.

Comment: ok, I found that one and downloaded it too but i'm not sure how to put the 2 together to make it work

Comment: so if i download Anaconda from say  https://pypi.python.org/simple/
 and unpack the tar ball and cd into it can i then use it?

Comment: @fred, well, I'd try placing the whole folder _inside_ `netcdf`, so that `netcdf/netcdf.py` could "see" it. Then try running your script again.

Comment: ok, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 1):

Easest would be to install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) or [Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html) with your user rights.
Anaconda already as `netCDF4`installed. In case of Miniconda install with:

```
conda install netcdf4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 3 installed, then you will have the `venv` package in the standard library, so you do not need "virtualenv" to be installed for you separately (as would be the case with Python 2).  Instead use `python3 -mvenv` , in a similar way to how you would use `virtualenv`, for example:

```
python3 -mvenv /path/to/my_venv
```

or to include any non-standard packages already installed on the system:

```
python3 -mvenv --system-site-packages /path/to/my_venv
```

After that, you should be able to activate the environment and `pip install` packages, e.g.

```
source /path/to/my_venv/bin/activate   # for csh use activate.csh instead
pip install netCDF4
```

Remember to source the `activate` script at run time as well as installation time:

```
source /path/to/my_venv/bin/activate
python
```

and you should then find that in your python session you have the `netCDF4` package available, e.g.

```
import netCDF4
my_dataset = netCDF4.Dataset('myfile.nc')
```

Of course, substitute the actual path in place of `/path/to/my_venv` above.

None of this requires any root privileges.

(And as someone else has suggested, another option for you is to use conda.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to highlight that the package is imported using capitals

```
import netCDF4 as nc
```

This might not matter on a mac, but for Windows it is key.