# Install numpy in Python 2.7 without setting environment

Tags: windows, python-2.7, numpy, installation

I wanted to install numpy in python 2.7 without setting environment path. I do not know if that is possible or not but my Professor wants it like so please any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. You can simply delete python from your environment path. But normally this is not desirable since you then cannot call python from any directory. Better is to create a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). Or better use: [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/). This will allow you to use various version of pythons in separate environments without any confusion or clashes between versions. You then install the respective numpy version within a specific environment. See: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

If you mean want to install numpy but you do not have the previleges then your answer can be found here: [(Python) Use a library locally instead of installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it)

I hope this helps. If not, then please clarify your question.

Comment: I fixed it. If you want to run more than 1 python version in your computer without setting path then you need to search wheel module_name. for an example, if you want to install numpy simply do wheel numpy and it redirects you to pypi numpy page. after going there download compatible version of wheel(whl extension)which your OS supports and then  open command prompt by opening run(windows + r) and trype cmd in it. redirect to environment in which you want to install module and type pip install wheel_file_location. for an example pip install C:/User/name/Downloads/numpy.whl.