# How to install modules locally from python code

Tags: python

I have some python code `test.py`

It imports some modules such as `import numpy as np`

I want to be able to run this code using `python test.py`

However it fails because module numpy is not installed.

Is it possible to add a line to python code to automatically install a module if its not already installed?

Additionally is it possible to make the module install in the local folder to the `test.py` file, like a `.dll` in c++

Thanks

Comment: you can aloways uses `os.system("pip install numpy")` or `os.system("python -m pip install numpy")`. Eventually you can `import pip` because it is Python module and then you use it in your code. But for more details you would have to find documentation for `pip` module

Comment: thanks, you can post as answer if you like

Answer (score 3):

You can aloways uses

```
os.system("pip install numpy")
```

or

```
os.system("python -m pip install numpy").
```

or some functions from module `subprocess` to better control it.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("python -m pip install numpy", shell=True)
```

---

You could use `try/except` for this

```
try
    import numpy
except:
    os.system("python -m pip install numpy")
    import numpy
```

---

Eventually you can `import pip` because it is Python module and then you use it in your code. But for more details you would have to find documentation for pip module

---

**BTW:** I found example with `import pip` in [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

Comment: Is there any difference between using subprocess.run and os.system?

Comment: using functions from module `subprocess` you can better control it. You can get output, or error code.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by control it better?

Comment: with `output = subprocess.check_output()` you can assing displayed text to variable `output` and you can save it in log file to keep information if three was problem to install - and user can see it later.  Using `exit_code = subprocess.call()` you can get code which returns some programs to recognize if there was problem to run program.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you use python's virtual environment ([Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)) it installs those libraries locally in a specific folder.

You can read more about it in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059783/6460856).

To install any library you could do the following thing:

```py
import os # This step is important
os.system("pip install yourModule")
```

This will install the module if it doesn't exists! (Ps: it doesn't throw any error if it's already present, so there's no need for error handling as well!)