# Difference between ways to import files from different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

According to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059699/python-use-a-library-locally-instead-of-installing-it) , it is said that to use a library or file from local folder, we use:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/directory")
```

But what my doubt is that, is :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/directory")
```

and:

```
locals()['path'].append("/path/to/your/directory")
```

and:

```
globals()['path'].append("/path/to/your/directory")
```

do the same function to import the directory files, or do vary by de-merits?
(I haven't seen any discussion about this anywere else)
[image]

Comment: This will raise `KeyError: 'path'` in my device..

Comment: Thats is when you start a shell painly. run a .py in shell and then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hacking" the sys.path to enable imports is bad practice. Use [editable installs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) instead:

```
pip install --editable /path/to/your/directory
```

This will insert a symlink of your project into the site-packages folder and 
allow Python to properly find your packages.